# Form text cursor wrong-sized when no text is entered

Tags: html, css

I made a form and its input text.

**HTML**

```
<form action="/search" method="get" id="searchForm"><input type="text" id="searchText" name="q" value="{SearchQuery}" /></form>
```

**CSS**

```
 #searchText {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: -2px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    width: 496px;
    font: 2em "Myriad", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #222222;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 2em;
 }

 #searchForm {
 }
```

And it works perfectly but looks like this:
[image: 1]
Notice how the cursor is moved down and not centered vertically.

Then, when any text is entered, it corrects itself to the right size/ vertical position and becomes 
[image]
(and even stays correct when text is deleted).

How can I make it also initialise correctly?

I've tried setting the

```
#searchForm { }
```

to   `vertical-align: center;`
     `line-height: normal;` or `inherit`
     `font-size: 1;`
but to no effect.

Comment: try padding-bottom:5px;

Comment: @singhiskng thanks - please see the response to Suresh - it is the same effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix suggestion :

```
padding: 2px 0;
```

would solve your problem

```
#searchText {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: -2px;
    padding: 2px 0; /* altered */
    width: 496px;
    font: 2em "Myriad", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: -2em;
    color: #222222;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 2em;
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8b05v9j0/)

**why its happening**

`padding-top: 5px;` is pushing down the cursor by `5px`...since your are not balancing this `padding` from `bottom` cursor is forced to *push* down!

Comment: thanks - it does work in your demo but not in my setup - I'll check everything in a second

Comment: @ValKalinic : hmmm...one there is a possibility that some other css is interfering with this one....can you check that!?

Comment: @ValKalinic : is cursor appearing pushed towards top now?

Comment: thanks - that's what I was checking for but I don't think so. It might be a browser issue, but then why doesn't it occur with your Demo? It does appear pushed to top now, why?

Comment: I think this is what's going on - for some reason the initial cursor changes when value first added - your solution changes the whole appearance (both initial and when value added) practically moving them both up but what would fix this is making it initialise correctly. Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: @ValKalinic : [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8b05v9j0/2/) check if this is more helpful...added a placeholder for more clear view with padding adjustment!

Answer (score 1):

Apply `equal padding` on top and bottom like below. Also remove the `top:-2px`.

```
 #searchText {
text-align: center;
position: relative;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
width: 496px;
font: 2em "Myriad", Helvetica, sans-serif;
line-height: 1;
color: #222222;
border: 1px solid gray;
border-radius: 2em;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/njvbr7oz/)

Comment: thanks @Suresh - it does make the initial cursor look better but it still changes when text is entered. And it persists no matter whether I equalise the top and bottom padding or remove them both. (all with top:-2px removed)

Comment: looks fine for me in chrome latest version. which browser you are using?

Comment: thank you, I am using Safari but now I see Firefox and iOS all act differently. So this is a browser issue only?

Comment: even though it appears a tad different in different browsers, it does change its size/position when value is entered - same as NoobEditor's answer - your solution changes the whole appearance (both initial and when value added) practically moving them both up but what would fix this is making it initialise correctly. Any ideas? Thank you